# How to register an onclick event so it knows the object it is called from?

Tags: javascript

I have some simple HTML & Javascript code:

```
<span id="test">Hej</span>

function Hello(el)
{
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    this.test = function(fun)
    {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e)
        {
            fun(e);
        }, false); 
    }
}   

var hello = new Hello;
hello.test(function()
{
    console.log(this);
});
```

I would like to use "this" in console.log() but I want it to refer to the instance of hello. 
How should I change the definition of Hello?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Function#call`, which lets you bind `this` to whatever you want:

```
function Hello(el)
{
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    var that = this;
    this.test = function(fun)
    {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e)
        {
            fun.call(that, e);
        }, false); 
    }
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jWMe/).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about this "call" method :)

Answer (score 1):

In your this.test function replace:

```
fun(e);
```

With:

```
fun.call(that, e);
```

And add the following before your event listener:

```
var that = this;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it to the passed function. The method `addEventListener` already provides you with access to the calling element through the usage of the `this` keyword in the specified listener function. So in order for this object to make it to your "fun" function, it needs to be passed as a variable.

```
function Hello(el)
{
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    this.test = function(fun)
    {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e)
        {
            fun(e, this);   // Adding the parameters to pass
        }, false); 
    }
}   

var hello = new Hello();
hello.test(function(event, el)  // The passed function should be ready to receive it
{
    alert(el.innerText);  
});
```

I tested it with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7E2s/).

**Edit:** Not sure I read the question fully the first time, but if you want to have access to `Hello` from within the function, you'll need to provide an instance of it from within your "class definition".

```
function Hello(el)
{
    var self = this;
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    this.test = function(fun)
    {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e)
        {
            fun(e, self);   // Adding the parameters to pass
        }, false); 
    }

    this.someProperty = "to test the value";
}   

var hello = new Hello();
hello.test(function(event, obj)  // The passed function should be ready to receive it
{
    alert(obj.someProperty);  
});
```

I tested this second version with [this fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/L7E2s/2/).